# Java syntax with " : "

Tags: java, syntax

I've seen this character used in c# like an extends in Java, but recently I found this in a code

`loop:      while (!stop) {}`

and also "pockets: "....it is followed by a for and inside that for there's "break pockets;"
And I have no idea what that it means. I would appreciate any explanation.

Comment: I think you are talking about the 'for each' loop? `for (something : collection) {...}` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html

Comment: [Branching statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html)

Comment: @Gosu no, he is talking about labels.

Comment: Oh okay, sorry!! That was what came to mind first, with `for` and `:`.

Comment: @Gosu well, in this case it is necessary to know where the ':' is, either inside the 'for' or outside :D.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's called a `label` and it's used for *naming* loops. It's useful when you have nested loops and you want to apply `break;` (or `continue;`) to a particular one. For example:

```
outer: for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   inner : for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
       if (i + j == 9) { 
           break outer;
       }
   }
}
```